# Adobe CQ: authoring content once to display in multiple components

Tags: content-management-system, adobe, aem

Is there any way to create components in CQ with content pre-added, so that authors can easily pull in a component that has the exact same content on each page where it appears?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes , it can be done by adding a cq:template[nt:unstructured] node under your component. If all the data is stored on the component node itself , add the default values as properties to cq:template node with name same as the ones in your dialog. In case the data is stored in a child node add a similar node under cq:template node.

**Source** : http://blogs.adobe.com/experiencedelivers/experience-management/defaults-in-your-component/

Comment: are you looking for "defaults" or for an out of box "xref" component (that stays updated)?